# Java decode hex values using utf-8 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to decode some hex values to their actual names, but i am having issue.

21043D0438043C043E043A04 should be decoded to СНИМОК.
Current code I am using

```
String test = "21043D0438043C043E043A04";
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(test.toCharArray());               
String a = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

but i am getting some pretty weird results.

Tried also getting it as utf8 bytes but did not work.

```
byte[] bytesone = test.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String b = new String(bytesone, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(b.toCharArray());              
String a = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code used to encode the text?

Comment: sadly i am having these values in a file

Comment: What class is `Hex`?

Comment: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

Comment: The string "21043D0438043C043E043A04" is not a utf-8 hex encoding of "СНИМОК". "d0a1d09dd098d09cd09ed09a" is.

Comment: Did a quick test with `"СНИМОК".getBytes("UTF-16LE")` and the result is `21041D0418041C041E041A04` - so your data is indeed encoded using UTF-16LE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u0421` is the Cyrillic `С` so the code seems UTF-16LE (little endian).

```
String a = new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
String a = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer ! Strangely enough I am now getting ?????? in the console.

Comment: The console is probably OS dependent with its encoding, that cannot handle Cyrillic script. Unrepresentable Unicode code points, will be converted to a place holder.

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like UTF-16LE.